# Grep out users whose device id is changing

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Consider the following log:

```
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:33.579`user_id=1`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:35.961`user_id=1`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:38.961`user_id=2`device_id=2
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:40.993`user_id=2`device_id=2
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:41.729`user_id=3`device_id=3
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:46.075`user_id=3`device_id=4
.....(more logs)
```

How Can I grep out users whose device_id is changing?

The output which I expect is:

```
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:41.729`user_id=3`device_id=3
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:46.075`user_id=3`device_id=4
```

Comment: Is the input grouped by user_id? Does the output have to be in order? Does this have to work in a pipeline or can we assume a seekable file?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. We can't fix things that we can't see.

Comment: What if you have a sequence like `user_id=1 device_id=1`, `user_id=1 device_id=2`, `user_id=1 device_id=1`, `user_id=1 device_id=1`? Which of those lines should be output?

Comment: @melpomene good question. I've answered with your question in mind. Which gives a lot of output. ;-) At least OP could propose to put a single line with timestamp of change, userid, device from, device to.

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution. The way I understood the question is: show every change in device per user. I've changed the inputfile a bit:

```
$ cat ch.txt
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:33.579`user_id=1`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:35.961`user_id=1`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:38.961`user_id=2`device_id=2
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:38.961`user_id=2`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:40.993`user_id=2`device_id=2
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:40.993`user_id=2`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:41.729`user_id=3`device_id=3
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:46.075`user_id=3`device_id=4

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]+|`" }
!($3 in usr) { usr[$3] = $0; dev[$3] = $4 }
{
  if ( $4 != dev[$3] ){ print usr[$3]; print $0; usr[$3] = $0; dev[$3] = $4 }
}
```

Explanation:

- FS="[[:space:]]+|`": use space and ` as field separator
- Whenever you've found a change in device

  - you print the original line usr[$3]
  - you print the current line $0
  - you need to save the current line ($0) in usr[$3]
  - you need to save the current device ($4) in dev[$3]

And then:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk ch.txt
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:38.961`user_id=2`device_id=2
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:38.961`user_id=2`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:38.961`user_id=2`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:40.993`user_id=2`device_id=2
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:40.993`user_id=2`device_id=2
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:40.993`user_id=2`device_id=1
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:41.729`user_id=3`device_id=3
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:46.075`user_id=3`device_id=4
```

EDIT: I hate this output. What if we change it to:

```
 cat tst2.awk
 BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]+|`|=" }
 !($5 in dev) { dev[$5] = $7 }
 {
    if ( $7 != dev[$5] ){
       print $2 OFS $3 ": user " $5 " changed device from " dev[$5] " to " $7;
       dev[$5] = $7
    }
 }
```

which generates:

```
$ awk -f tst2.awk ch.txt
2017-08-29 11:25:38.961: user 2 changed device from 2 to 1
2017-08-29 11:25:40.993: user 2 changed device from 1 to 2
2017-08-29 11:25:40.993: user 2 changed device from 2 to 1
2017-08-29 11:25:46.075: user 3 changed device from 3 to 4
2017-08-29 11:25:33.579: user 1 changed device from 1 to 2
```

Comment: Your constructs `!usr[$3]` and `!dev[$3]` cause those array subscripts to exist, and may be evaluated incorrectly if the array content is a literal `0` (which is still not null). A better way to test array membership in awk is `$3 in usr`. Compare: `echo 0 | awk '{a[NF]=$1} a[NF] {print "yo"}'` vs `echo 0 | awk '{a[NF]=$1} NF in a {print "yo"}'` ... And also, `echo 0 | awk 'a[NF] {print "foo"} NF in a {print "bar"}'`. Note that nothing appears to set `a[NF]` here, but it's set implicitly by the first test. Might not be a factor for this particular dataset, but good habits are .. good. :)

Comment: Agreed. I suppose !dev[$3] is just a typo. +1

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+|`|=' 'uid && $5==uid && $7!=did{ print r ORS $0 }
     { uid=$5; did=$7; r=$0 }' file
```

- ``` -F'[[:space:]]+|``|=' ``` - compound field separator
- `uid=$5; did=$7; r=$0` - capturing *user_id* `uid`, *device_id* `did` and current record `r`

---

The output:

```
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:41.729`user_id=3`device_id=3
tm=2017-08-29 11:25:46.075`user_id=3`device_id=4
```

Comment: This makes a few assumptions, such as: No id is ever `0`. The input is grouped by `user_id`. There are at most two lines with the same `user_id` in a row (otherwise it will swallow or duplicate lines).